# Question Mark is occured on Laravel query

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to run code below in Laravel
 $posts= DB::table('rmm')

```
        ->select( array('message', DB::raw('COUNT(message) as number'), DB::raw('rmm.receivedTime as time')))

        ->join( 'rcs', 'rmm.smsCid', '=', 'rcs.smsCid', 'INNER') 

        ->where(DB::raw('rcs.status =1 and rmm.receivedTime > \'2012-12-26\' and rmm.receivedTime LIKE \'2013-04-01\' and length(\'message\') >\'3\' '))

        ->group_by('message')

        ->get();
```

and got the error code below

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? GROUP BY `message`' at line 1

```
SQL: SELECT `message`, COUNT(message) as number, rmm.receivedTime as time FROM `rmm` INNER JOIN `rcs` ON `rmm`.`smsCid` = `rcs`.`smsCid` WHERE rcs.status =1 and rmm.receivedTime > '2012-12-26' and rmm.receivedTime LIKE '2013-04-01' and length('message') >'3'   ? GROUP BY `message`

Bindings: array (
  0 => NULL,
)
```

somehow it produces `?` on query; I'm sure it will work if I solve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `raw_where()`:

```
->raw_where("rcs.status = 1 AND rmm.receivedTime > '2012-12-26' AND rmm.receivedTime LIKE '2013-04-01' AND length('message') > 3")
```

Comment: yeah but i just want to check the length of message, you query check for length of whole db::raw

Comment: it works, but your query checks for the length of the whole DB::Raw-attention for brackets, I just wanted to check for only the message length

Comment: It seems like this but in the raw query it must be `length('message') > 3` .. Did you get a syntax error? Or query result is different than expected?

Comment: i mean the brackets of db::raw, shouldn't it cover the whole query? btw your query works fine but produced result is unexpected.